# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server in wamp

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am installed `wamp`  both in server and in my local machine. In local machine this is working fine. But some issues happened in server. While I log in to the `phpmyadmin`  **#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server** error shows. How I can solve this?

My **config.inc.php** file contain the following code

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'admin';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Please help me.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.

I followed the instructions just described as [here](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/). Follow the 4 steps and tried. And worked.

Now the **config.inc.php** is looks like this

```
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

This is same as described in the tutorial. So follow the all steps given in the link and restart the services. Will get worked. Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

Log in using the default password:

```
Username: root

Password: [null]
```

With [null] I mean no password at all.

Answer (score 3):

Just install "MySQL workbench" and it will ask for old and new passwords if already expired.

I had the same issue with my WAMP server and managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your password and set it to null as

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'null';
```

Answer (score 0):

WAMPServer has used

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

For a long time now, in order to make phpMyAdmin throw a login page. This is far more secure than storing a `user` and `password` in the config file, which would allow anyone to login to phpMyAdmin when inexperienced users decide to open their router up so they can show others their site.

So change your phpMyAdmins `config.inc.php` as above and enter the username and password on the login screen.

#### Note:

If you have not changed MySQL to have a password on the root account, then **leave the password field blank** on the login screen.